# Multiple push refresh button

Tags: c#

This code shows a select query in a listview.

On the second push of the button "refresh", it duplicates the result, and on the third enter in catch "Error".

I don't understand why the second works (not well because duplicate, but it works) and on the third there is an ERROR.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cm = con.CreateCommand();
    cm.CommandText = "Select * from H_Facturi_Clienti";

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();                             
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["H_Id"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Serie"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Numar"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Id_Partener"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Data"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Valoare"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);                  
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        statusLbl.Text = "Eroare ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Your `catch` block is ignoring the exception.  When trying to diagnose an error, *ignoring* the error isn't particularly helpful.  Also, where is the `con` object being created?  If you don't have a valid SQL connection then this won't work at all.

Comment: Don't re-use connections by storing them somewhere.  Connections are pooled by .NET, so creating them generally isn't an expensive operation, but keeping connections open can cause issues (especially if you _assume_ that they're already open).  Surround new connections and commands in `using` blocks to ensure that they are closed in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to clear your listView before re-loading it?

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
//then load list
```

Did you forget to close your `SqlDataReader` after finish its using?

```
dr.Close();
```

Comment: SqlDataReader is IDisposable, right? Prefer using blocks over manual closing!

Comment: listView1.Items.Clear() i've tried but not helpful, because i haven;'t dr.Close()